# Is there a reason RowSums(df[grep wouldn't work accurately?

Tags: r, rowsum

I used

```
df$Total.P.n <- rowSums(df[grep('p.n', names(df), ignore.case = FALSE)])
```

to sum count values from any column name containing `p.n`, but the values it produced are way off. The columns are counts of certain combinations of language types in a language corpus. I want to get a summary of all times `p.n`. was used within other combinations, but am struggling. It seems like perhaps it is counting other occurences like `e.sp.NR` in my variable names, but shouldn't `ignore.case=FALSE` take care of that? I've also tried `tidyverse` and `dplyr` solutions to no avail.

Here's example of `df` structure:

| ID. | do.p.n.NP | do.p.n.SE | p.d.e.sp.SR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1510 | 4 | 6 | 2 |
| 1515 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

and what I need:

| ID. | do.p.n.NP | do.p.n.SE | p.d.e.sp.SR | Total.P.n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1510 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 10 |
| 1515 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Maybe try `grepl` instead of `grep`?

Comment: please provide a proper reproducible example. Paste the output of `dput(df)` in your question

Comment: is the last column supposed to be c(0,1) as in the first table or c(2,1) as in the seccond one?

Comment: @GuedesBF, yes, sorry, I am working on this problem from COVID quarantine. I appreciate your patience with my mistakes. This is as close to a full reprex as I can do- it's restricted use data.

Answer (score 1):

**Update after update(new column names) of OP:**
The code is like:

```
df$Total.P.n <- rowSums(df[grep('p.n', names(df), ignore.case = FALSE)])
df$p.d.e.sp.SR <- rowSums(df[,2:3]!=0)
```

```
    ID. do.p.n.NP do.p.n.SE. p.d.e.sp.SR Total.P.n
1 1510         4          6           2        10
2 1515         2          0           1         2
```

**First answer:**
The argument pattern you are searching for e.g. `p.n` does not exist in `df`. Therefore I think you mean `pn`: Then your code works as expectect:

```
df$Total.P.n <- rowSums(df[grep('pn', names(df), ignore.case = FALSE)])
```

```
   ID. do.pn.NP do.pn.SE. p.d.e.sp.SR Total.P.n
1 1510        4         6           0        10
2 1515        2         0           1         2
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed this, but p.n. DOES exist in df. I've updated the reprex to reflect that.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: This regex is potentially fragile, as I suspect the OP wants to match literal dots. As is, the regex will also match "pxn", "pyn" or whatever. It works on the given example, but is likely not scalable.

Comment: Ok. I agree. Do you think `'p\\.n'` is better?. I think the main issue was that column `p.d.e.sp.SR` needs a own line of code to count cells that are not 0 thus providing to Total row sum. But it is a guess. What do you think?

Comment: I do not know. I just realized the OP updated the data, but their tables are inconsistent with one another. Different values for the `p.d.e.sp.SR` column. I asked for clarifications

Comment: anyway, both "p\\.n" and "p.n" do not match "p.d.e.sp.SR", so these work.

Answer (score 0):

If we can use dplyr, I would suggest using a tidy-select function / selection helper like `matches`. And please mind that your regex is likely wrong. If we need to match literal dots `.` , we need to escape the metacharacter with a double backslash. The appropriate regex would be `n\\.p`.

```
library(dplyr)
```

**data**

```
df <- tibble(`ID.` = c(1510, 1515), `do.p.n.NP` = c(4,2), `do.p.n.SE.` = c(6,0), `p.d.e.sp.SR` = c(0,1))
```

**answer**

```
df %>%
    mutate(Total.P.n = rowSums(across(matches('p\\.n'))))

# A tibble: 2 × 5
    ID. do.p.n.NP do.p.n.SE. p.d.e.sp.SR Total.P.n
  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1  1510         4          6           0        10
2  1515         2          0           1         2
```

Comment: this is the error I get when I use the above code: Error in (function (cond)  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: It is working just fine here. Plese check if you are using the exact same synthax

Comment: Please see the updated answer